# sql query does not give any value

Tags: c#, sql-server

it does not gave any value

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Paied) FROM Debt", new SqlConnection(Program.ConnectionString)))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    TotalPaiedAll = Convert.ToDecimal( myReader["Paied"].ToString());
                }
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code and accept some of your questions.

Comment: well, we're here to help and be helped, aren't we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're not getting a value is because `SUM(Paied)` generates an anonymous column, not a column named Paied.

Here is a simple fix for your problem:

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Paied) As SumOfPaid FROM Debt", new SqlConnection(Program.ConnectionString))) 
        { 
            cmd.Connection.Open(); 
            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            while (myReader.Read()) 
            {
                TotalPaiedAll = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["SumOfPaid"].ToString()); 
            } 
            cmd.Connection.Close(); 
        }
```

And here is a better approach, using the ExecuteScalar method:

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Paied) As SumOfPaid FROM Debt", new SqlConnection(Program.ConnectionString)))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            TotalPaiedAll = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: It was so simple! Yet I din't get it when I saw the question at first glance.. +1

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL query should be

```
SELECT SUM(Paied) AS Paied FROM Debt
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
SELECT SUM(Paied) AS Paied FROM Debt

TotalPaiedAll = (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

use executescalar instead of executereader:

```
decimal sum =(decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

there is no point in doing a while loop because the sum is just a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Not your bug but you also need to protect the sql connection against leakage.